# A script to change a directory's permissions and owner immediately after it is created?

Tags: bash, file-permissions, watch, file-ownership

I have the ability to create directories, but I have a problem where...

I cannot continue to access directories that might require a second or third operation after their initial creation; so, I want to create a script with admin access that can change the owner and set the correct permissions every time a directory is added.

How do I create a scriptfile and give it sufficient permissions to change the permissions and owners of other files?  And how do I then set up a watch on my directory and all of its recursive children such that any time a new directory is created, its permissions and ownership are set to the desired state?

Also, for the sake of learning, **if you have a better way to achieve the result**, please tell me how to achieve the result in the method described above?  I'm very interested to know how to monitor a folder and its children and trigger a script.

Comment: `inotifywait` from `inotifytools` comes to mind.

Comment: Take a look at `umask` and [sticky bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit). That might be enough.